# referencing fields that belong to another model class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

I'am using devise and set the name of my model to User. When i created post model i entered the following:

```
 rails g model Post title body:text user:references
```

on the index page for the post partial views I can see the id number for all users whenever user makes post with following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="row">
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1><%= post.title %> <small>by: 
       <%= post.user_id %></small></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the @posts variable in my post controller class is:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

basically what I'am trying to do is get user email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).all
```

In the view:

```
post.user.email
```

Recommendation:
Use pagination as fetching all records at once is not feasible and scalable in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reach through your model to get the associated model:

```
<%= post.user.email %>
```

Comment: this will be N+1

Comment: `@posts = Post.preload(:user).all`